# Oauth WARN [HttpMethodDirector] Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {token=Token}

Tags: salesforce-id, oauth2, java, oauth

I'm just a beginner with Salesforce Oauth. When I try to get the access token with username/password flow everything seem good. This is out put:

```
> Status-Code: 200
Auth response: {
  "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000xXXXXXX/0059000000XXXXXXXX",
  "issued_at": "0000000000000",
  "instance_url": "https://ap1.salesforce.com",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "00D90000000xJDp!ARAAQEPz2HncPKS_z5pESC0dgXM8D3GcwRkrMs_2EjwY8Ll_oTVOvHvd7h7rh1dZ.Aknci8.vJCFvd8H.eRJJDNqFU0TfzA0",
  "signature": "ioPU6/NMMhEdmR6xF7SaCSGGeoR2wmKjXZ4AF4ckH5Q="
}
```

In few hour late and it show:

```
> Status-Code: 200
Auth response: {
  "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D90000000xJDpEAM/00590000002JFlGAAW",
  "issued_at": "1407922487655",
  "instance_url": "https://ap1.salesforce.com",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "00D90000000xJDp!ARAAQEPz2HncPKS_z5pESC0dgXM8D3GcwRkrMs_2EjwY8Ll_oTVOvHvd7h7rh1dZ.Aknci8.vJCFvd8H.eRJJDNqFU0TfzA0",
  "signature": "ioPU6/NMMhEdmR6xF7SaCSGGeoR2wmKjXZ4AF4ckH5Q="
}
> 
> 16:34:49,579 WARN  [HttpMethodDirector] Unable to respond to any of
> these challenges: {token=Token}
```

I do not understand why the the WARN show up? Can someone tell me?

Updated the code.

```
System.out.println("Getting a token");
    tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token";
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(tokenUrl);     
    post.addParameter("grant_type", "password");
    post.addParameter("client_id", clientId);
    post.addParameter("client_secret", clientSecret);
    post.addParameter("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
    post.addParameter("username", username);
    post.addParameter("password", password);

    try {
        httpclient.executeMethod(post);
        System.out.println("Status-Code: " + post.getStatusCode());
        try {
            JSONObject authResponse = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new InputStreamReader(post.getResponseBodyAsStream())));
            System.out.println("Auth response: " + authResponse.toString(2));

            accessToken = authResponse.getString("access_token");
            instanceUrl = authResponse.getString("instance_url");

            System.out.println("Got access token: " + accessToken);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    } catch (HttpException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }       

    System.out.println("We have an access token: " + accessToken + "\n" + "Using instance " + instanceUrl + "\n\n");


    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(instanceUrl + "/services/data/v28.0/query");

    // set the token in the header
    get.setRequestHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
```

Comment: This is not an answer for your question, but it's better to replace any confidential data(with 'X' marks or something) when you post something here.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code where you're making the callouts for oAuth?

Comment: Updated the code, Sir.